# How can I fix this tensorflow saver restore error which occurs when repeatedly using the def function of estimation model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, restore

I made an estimation model using tensorflow and keras, and made this model into a def function with tf.train.Saver.

However, repeated use of this def function occurs the following error.

What is the reason for this error and how can I fix it?

**the def function of estimation model in 'Model.py'**

```
def LSTM_Model(input_data):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 20, 121], name="input")

    with tf.variable_scope('LSTM'):
        y_pred = Lsss(x)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=4)
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(
            'C:\LSTM\LSTM_model3\LSTM_paper_2_mean20_4_3_epoch_31_look_back_20_1\Result3')
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)

        K.set_learning_phase(False)

        height = sess.run([y_pred], {x: input_data})

    return height[0][0]
```

**main function**

```
from Model import LSTM_Model
from numpy import *
import hdf5storage
import numpy as np

def main():

    filename = 'Datafile'
    mat_file = hdf5storage.loadmat('C:/LSTM/Data/'+filename+'.mat')
    TrainSet = mat_file['Trainingset'][0]
    Train_time = mat_file['Train_time'][0]
    trainnum = 0
    data1 = TrainSet[trainnum]

    before_data = data1[Train_time[trainnum]-20:Train_time[trainnum], 0:121]
    input_data = np.reshape(before_data, (1, 20, 121))
    height = LSTM_Model(input_data)*1000
    print(height)
    height = LSTM_Model(input_data)*1000
    print(height)
```

**Occurred error**

```
C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/LSTM/main.py
[544.562]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1356, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1341, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1429, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Not found: Key LSTM_1/cu_dnnlstm_3/bias not found in checkpoint
     [[{{node save_1/RestoreV2}}]]
  (1) Not found: Key LSTM_1/cu_dnnlstm_3/bias not found in checkpoint
     [[{{node save_1/RestoreV2}}]]
     [[save_1/RestoreV2/_37]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1286, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 950, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1173, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1350, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1370, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Not found: Key LSTM_1/cu_dnnlstm_3/bias not found in checkpoint
     [[node save_1/RestoreV2 (defined at \LSTM\Model.py:35) ]]
  (1) Not found: Key LSTM_1/cu_dnnlstm_3/bias not found in checkpoint
     [[node save_1/RestoreV2 (defined at \LSTM\Model.py:35) ]]
     [[save_1/RestoreV2/_37]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

Original stack trace for 'save_1/RestoreV2':
  File "/LSTM/main.py", line 114, in <module>
    main()
  File "/LSTM/main.py", line 96, in main
    height = LSTM_Model(input_data)*1000
  File "\LSTM\Model.py", line 35, in LSTM_Model
    saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=4)
  File "\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 825, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 837, in build
    self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
  File "\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 875, in _build
    build_restore=build_restore)
  File "\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 508, in _build_internal
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 328, in _AddRestoreOps
    restore_sequentially)
  File "\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 575, in bulk_restore
    return io_ops.restore_v2(filename_tensor, names, slices, dtypes)
  File "\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_io_ops.py", line 1780, in restore_v2
    name=name)
  File "\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 788, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3616, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2005, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1296, in restore
    names_to_keys = object_graph_key_mapping(save_path)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1614, in object_graph_key_mapping
    object_graph_string = reader.get_tensor(trackable.OBJECT_GRAPH_PROTO_KEY)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 678, in get_tensor
    return CheckpointReader_GetTensor(self, compat.as_bytes(tensor_str))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Key _CHECKPOINTABLE_OBJECT_GRAPH not found in checkpoint

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/LSTM/main.py", line 114, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/LSTM/main.py", line 96, in main
    height = LSTM_Model(input_data)*1000
  File "C:\LSTM\Model.py", line 39, in LSTM_Model
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1302, in restore
    err, "a Variable name or other graph key that is missing")
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a Variable name or other graph key that is missing from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original error:

2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Not found: Key LSTM_1/cu_dnnlstm_3/bias not found in checkpoint
     [[node save_1/RestoreV2 (defined at \LSTM\Model.py:35) ]]
  (1) Not found: Key LSTM_1/cu_dnnlstm_3/bias not found in checkpoint
     [[node save_1/RestoreV2 (defined at \LSTM\Model.py:35) ]]
     [[save_1/RestoreV2/_37]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

Original stack trace for 'save_1/RestoreV2':
  File "/LSTM/main.py", line 114, in <module>
    main()
  File "/LSTM/main.py", line 96, in main
    height = LSTM_Model(input_data)*1000
  File "\LSTM\Model.py", line 35, in LSTM_Model
    saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=4)
  File "\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 825, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 837, in build
    self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
  File "\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 875, in _build
    build_restore=build_restore)
  File "\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 508, in _build_internal
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 328, in _AddRestoreOps
    restore_sequentially)
  File "\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 575, in bulk_restore
    return io_ops.restore_v2(filename_tensor, names, slices, dtypes)
  File "\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_io_ops.py", line 1780, in restore_v2
    name=name)
  File "\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 788, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3616, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2005, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()


Process finished
```

Comment: Did you manage to find any solutions?